# Jquery ajax returning blank response

Tags: jquery, ajax

This code is returning blank array. I am posting to PHP script with code.

PHP:

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Jquery Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // --------------------------------------------------------------
        // Submit danasnji dan
        // --------------------------------------------------------------
        $("a#danasnji-submit").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var lokacija = $("input#base-url").val()+"/uporabnik/umakniRezervacije";
            var podatki = $("table#danasnji-dan tbody tr.clicked");
            var izbrano = new Array();
            if(confirm("Ali ste prepričani?")){
                podatki.each(function(){
                    izbrano.push($(this).data());
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : lokacija,
                    data : izbrano,
                    success : function(vrnjeno){
                        alert(vrnjeno);
                        $("table#danasnji-dan tbody tr.clicked").each(function(){
                            $(this).fadeOut();
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong. Please, any ideas?

Comment: How about some google chrome dev or firebug?

Comment: Chrome dev tools show no errors..

Comment: Do you know that you have rows selected in your table, which will end up building your array that you're passing to your PHP page?  Can you confirm that the array is actually being built?

Comment: yes, the array is built i checked with console.log. Also if i use any other varible for data it is just not passed :/

Comment: @user1141356: and what about ajax request? Does chrome dev tools show that your browser performs ajax requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the problem. Since I was posting to PHP, the script had to retrieve that value by name. You can't just post a value withou variable holding it.

So, the solution is this. Key value pair

```
data : {
  'Varible' : 'Value'
}
```

Thanks for your help anyway,
cheers